# Input[file] .click() not working in Firefox KeyboardEvent

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

When pressing <kbd>CTRL + O</kbd> it should trigger the input of type file by `fileInput.click()` - wich opens the File-Open-Dialog (just as clicking on `<input type="file" />` by hand).

Now in most Browsers my Code does work does work, but not in Firefox:

https://jsfiddle.net/ue9Lrc7a/3/

```
var fileInput = document.createElement("input")
fileInput.type = "file"

function load() {
  alert("loaded: " + fileInput.files.length)
}

function onkey(ev) {
  if (ev.keyCode == 79 /*KEY O*/ && ev.ctrlKey) {
    fileInput.click()
    ev.preventDefault()
    return false
  }
}


fileInput.addEventListener("change", (function(ipt) {
  return function() {
    load();
    ipt.value = null;
  }
})(fileInput))
window.addEventListener("keydown", onkey)
```

Is there a way to make Firefox open the Dialog as well?*

**Note: it works when `click()` is triggerend in a MouseEvent, but not in the KeyboardEvent*

**On [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) it says Firefox has input@file (full) support*

Comment: I guess you probably have to simulate a real mouse event (instead of ``.click()``). Have you tried using something like ``new MouseEvent()``. Though it might be a little laborious, it could work. Haven't tried it though.

Comment: @GuidoKitzing Following the example on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent): https://jsfiddle.net/ue9Lrc7a/4/ - but it does not work for the file-input. For the CheckBox it does however! Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Yeah not you.. is it a bad question or what is wrong?

Comment: I think there will be an interesting answer to this. I was not aware of the problem until you brought it up.

Comment: the problem is firefox also uses `Ctrl+O`(to open a local file). thus `<input type="file">` tag can not catch that event. try an unused key, IMO that may work

Comment: @RajKamal Thats not a problem, you can catch any key-command before the Browser and stop him from using it, as you can see in the example.